# Rails how to selected dropdown based on query params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I new to Rails so I try to build a filter dropdown using HTML Select

I tried to selected dropdown based on query params but it is not working

**test.com/orders?category=TRANSACTION_REGISTRATION**

This is my constant

```
CATEGORIES = {
    "TRANSACTION_REGISTRATION" => "TRANSACTION REGISTRATION",
    "TRANSACTION_CANCELLATION" => "TRANSACTION CANCELLATION",
  }
```

This is my form

```
<select class="form-control" name="category">
     <option value="">Select option</option>
     <% Order::CATEGORIES.each do |order, index| %>
         <option value="<%= order %>" <% if :params['category'] %>selected="selected"<% end %> ><%= index %></option>
     <% end %>
</select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have syntax error at :params['category']. Here is the final solution for those looking for same quetion

```
<select class="form-control" name="category">
                          <option value="">Select option</option>
                          <% Order::CATEGORIES.each do |order, index| %>
                            <option value="<%= order %>" <% if params[:category] === order %>selected="selected"<% end %> ><%= index %></option>
                          <% end %>
                        </select>
```